# JSF 2 custom 404 error page does not get displayed with non existing pages that have the configured facelet extension

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, http-status-code-404, facelets

I a working on a JSF2/Spring3/JPA2 project using facelets as view technology.

`javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX` is `.xhtml` and the `url-pattern` for `Faces Servlet` is `*.xhtml`

We are also using prettyfaces but it seems irrelevant to my problem that I'll explain below.

We are on Tomcat 7.

We decided to show up custom 404 error pages and created a page called `error404.xhtml` at the web root. We also configured it in `web.xml` as:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Now when I try to enter `http://localhost:8084/myapp/some-non-existing-folder` I get the 404 page and an expected 404 response.

But when I try to enter `http://localhost:8084/myapp/some-non-existing-page.xhtml` I get a blank page from Tomcat, no error, and the resonse header is 200 OK.

We're kind of stuck at this point and clueless since there is no output, log, error whatsoever that can point us in any direction.

Thanks

Comment: btw, we are using jsf 2.1.4 on tomcat 7.0.22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this some thing like the login page for your application or ur trying to deeplink the page or to navigate to that particular page.As its some thing like a page not found and ur trying to access that the first link would be working fine.But,for the second one http://localhost:8084/myapp/some-non-existing-page.xhtml.There might be an exception generated.So if you can write a custom exception handler and direct the page to your required detination.This issue can be resolved.